# How would I remove part of string before and after specific characters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having a bit of an issue separating strings that contain multiple special characters.

[image]

I wish to separate the colours and not bring any of the special characters, I have been playing around with Charindex but it does not work well.

eg:

```
SELECT [Color combo]
  ,left([Color combo], CHARINDEX('.'  , replace([Color combo]) - 1)   AS [Primary]

FROM [test].[dbo].[Palate]
```

This errors out as when it hits line 3 with the"/"
is there a way to filter multiple special characters?

Comment: Do you want remove special characters ?

Comment: can you please provide what you would be looking for as an end result.

Comment: What are you trying to do?please show expected outputs

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not paste pictures! Nobody wants to type in your test scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand , that should answer your question :

```
declare @T table (Id INT , Color_combo varchar(500) );
insert into @t values (1,'Pink.Blue') , (2,'Orange.White') , (3,'Yellow.Orange') , (4,'Red/Green') , (5,':Green.Purple\');

SELECT
        Id,
        Color_combo,
        LEFT(Color_combo, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Color_combo, 0) > 0
                               THEN CHARINDEX('.', Color_combo, 0) - 1
                               ELSE
                               CHARINDEX('/', Color_combo, 0) - 1
                          END)  AS [Primary],
        RIGHT(Color_combo, LEN(color_combo) - (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Color_combo, 0) > 0
                                THEN CHARINDEX('.', Color_combo, 0)
                                ELSE
                                CHARINDEX('/', Color_combo, 0)
                           END)) AS [Secondary]
FROM    @T;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IKX24129)